# How to read and write a file in Azure IoT edge module

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to read and write a file programmatically in the IoT edge module.

**Scenario:**

I have created a file locally in my directory which I am trying to read and write through python code like this:

```
  lines = open(my_file_name, 'r').readlines()
  print("LINES")
  print(lines)
  lines[line_num] = text # Modifying a line to check if the changes persist
  out = open(my_file_name, 'w')
  out.writelines(lines)
  out.close()
```

The problem is that when the module runs on the simulator(locally), it reads the file correctly but when it comes to writing it does not write to that particular file. If it can read that file, it should be able to write that file. It could be that since the simulator runs through a docker container so that it writes the file to the container and I cannot see those changes in my local Visual studio code editor. This seems to be the plausible explanation but still not sure. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Philip mentioned, you need to use the createOptions in the deployment.template.json file to mount a host directory into the container. I haven't found good IoTEdge related documentation on how to do this. I was successful with this task by setting up a bind mount on my module's create options. With Windows, it looks something like this

```
    "modules": {
      "ExtrusionDataCapture": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "settings": {
          "image": "${MODULEDIR<../ExtrusionDataCapture>}",
          "createOptions": {
            "HostConfig": {
              "Mounts": [
                {
                  "Type": "bind",
                  "Source": "C:\\extrusion",
                  "Target": "C:\\iotdata",
                  "RW": true,
                  "Propagation": "rprivate"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerCreate

Comment: I'm trying to mount volume but I have the error `Could not create module: caused by: create /var/lib/docker/containers/: "/var/lib/docker/containers/" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path` I don't understand. How can I specify path with only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" ?

Comment: @iAmoric what is the name you are attempting to use. [a-zA-Z0-9]  (characters from a to z, A to Z, and 0 to 9) has quite a few characters which you can name your volume.

Comment: Yeah it's ok I found the solution. I was asking because in the path there are "/" which are obviously not in the range

Answer (score 0):

You need to use docker volume, provide it in create options for your iotedge module.